# How can I control other users while Presenting In BBB?

Tags: bigbluebutton

I want to use **BigBlueButton** as a **Smart Classroom**. But in the current configuration anyone can control as admin.
Eg:- Anyone logged into the system can change the presenter.
     Anyone can kickout another user from the system.

I want to stop this and use as one user is controlling everything.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the built-in API demos to try out BigBlueButton.  In many of these demos, everyone is logged in as a moderator and has full privileges.

In a real session, most students are logged in as viewers and they can't make themselves presenter.  Only a moderator can make someone (including themselves) a presenter.

For a better feel of how the roles work, try out our demo server at https://demo.bigbluebutton.org/ and authenticate with your Google or Twitter account.  This let's you create recorded sessions, join sessions as moderator, and invite others (via an invite URL), to join as a viewer.

For more details on how the roles work, see the tutorial videos as https://bigbluebutton.org/videos/.